# Using a Scaled Tolerance to Compare Floats

Tags: python, floating-point, compare, floating-accuracy

It occurred to me that a good way to compare floats is to scale the tolerance with the floats. Is it a good idea?

This routine needs to be expanded for special quantities, such as NaN, +/-Inf, but it gives a basic idea.

```
def FloatEq(a, b, ToleranceFactor=1e-6):
    if a == b: return True
    c = min(abs(a), abs(b))
    return(abs(a-b) < (c*ToleranceFactor))

a = 0.000000000001
b = 0.000000000001000000001

print('Straight compare ==', a==b)
print('FloatEq(,,1e-6) ==', FloatEq(a,b))
print('FloatEq(,,1e-10) ==', FloatEq(a,b,1e-10))
```

Output:

```
Straight compare == False
FloatEq(,,1e-6) == True
FloatEq(,,1e-10) == False
```

**UPDATE:**

One possible solution that can handle one of the operands being zero. It uses a fixed, user-configurable tolerance, rather than a factor.

```
def FloatEq(a, b, ToleranceFactor=1e-6, ToleranceAtZero=None):
    if a == b:
        return True
    elif a==0 or b==0:
        c = a if b==0 else b
        if ToleranceAtZero is None:
            import sys
            # Ignoring denormalized numbers for now
            ToleranceAtZero = sys.float_info.min
        return abs(c) < ToleranceAtZero
    else:
        c = min(abs(a), abs(b))
        return(abs(a-b) < (c*ToleranceFactor))
```

Comment: It depends on your use-case but I have seen worse attempts to compare floating-point values.  Just note that your logic is somewhat convoluted.  You could get rid of all the `if` / `else` stuff if you apply `abs` to the difference and use `min(abs(a), abs(b))`. Also note that your final `return` is bogus. Also think about the case that one value is exactly zero. What tolerance do you want to use in this case?

Comment: I cleaned it up. I want to apply the tolerance factor to the float with the lesser absolute value. If one value is zero, the result is `False`, which seems appropriate here.

Comment: why not just have: isEqual = lambda(t,a,b) : abs(a) - abs(b) < t ..then use it as isEqual(1e-6,a,b)

Comment: @JTurk You use a fixed value for tolerance. It is not scaled with the floats.

Comment: I dont follow why you would need to scale something by a tolerance factor as you do...when a simple compare wrt a tolerance factor works well for float comparison?...just curious...thats all

Comment: Shouldn't it be `c = min(abs(a), abs(b))`?  Your current version produces a negative `c` in some cases, leading to a never-true final comparison.  I think your idea is sane overall, though: the scaling the tolerance to the operands being compared makes sense if you expect the rounding error to scale linearly with your operands.  (i.e. they're not the result of subtracting two very close numbers.  In that case, you can have two small numbers with large errors.).

Comment: @JTurk It may be OK to say that `1000.0+0.0001 == 1000.0`, but not `0.00000001+0.0001 == 0.00000001`.

Comment: right ...if i know apriori the order of decimals/numbers I am comparing, i'd just increase the tolerance...

Comment: I think you are too optimistic about the zero case. For example, imagine you perform a root search for a function `f` that will return you an `x0` and you want to check whether you really found a root. You might write `assert FloatEq(f(x0), 0)`. Chances are little you'll ever pass that `assert`ion even though it seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @5gon12eder For some special cases around zero, it may be best to use a fixed tolerance value, and not this approach. It would depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sensible idea unless you're comparing values that could have been the result of [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) (e.g. subtracting two nearby numbers to produce a very small, very inaccurate, number.)  In that case, I think you should scale your tolerance by the magnitude of the pre-cancellation values.

I'm not a numerical calculation / floating point expert.  Getting this stuff right is Hard, and there's a whole stackexchange for it: [Computational Science.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Some searching turned up: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3362/relative-comparison-of-floating-point-numbers with several answers about FP comparison.